# Understanding App.config and using Configuration Manager: GetSection vs. ConnectionString

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

For some context, I want to open a connection to a database and execute some queries.

Here's my App.config:

```
    <dbservers>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="Cube_ConnectionString" connectionString="OLEDB; Datasource=http://cube.com; Initial Catalog=BP" />
        </connectionStrings>
        <queries>
            <add connectionStringName="CubeConnectionString" usedBy="DataAccessor" connectionString="" />
        </queries>
    </dbservers>
```

This is how I intend to retrieve the connectionString:

```
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cube_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

I am wondering whether GetSection or ConnectionString would be best to use. And what would be returned for both of them? How do these two methods function within nested XML such as this?

Additionally, what's the purpose of putting queries in the app.config?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `<dbservers>`? Is that a custom section?

Comment: Yea its a custom section. That was the part I'm a little unsure on. Would that mess with how the methods are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `ConnectionStrings` will work unless you put them in the standard section for those. If you want a custom `<dbservers>` section, you'll have to use `GetSection` instead.

This functionality is a bit awkward, but highly useful. [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.140).aspx) is a useful guide for this.

Essentially this boils down to creating a class that inherits from `ConfigurationSection`, and adding the proper attributes (from the above guide):

```
public class PageAppearanceSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    // Create a "remoteOnly" attribute.
    [ConfigurationProperty("remoteOnly", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = false)]
    public Boolean RemoteOnly
    {
        get
        { 
            return (Boolean)this["remoteOnly"]; 
        }
        set
        { 
            this["remoteOnly"] = value; 
        }
    }

    // Create a "font" element.
    [ConfigurationProperty("font")]
    public FontElement Font
    {
        get
        { 
            return (FontElement)this["font"]; }
        set
        { this["font"] = value; }
    }

    // Create a "color element."
    [ConfigurationProperty("color")]
    public ColorElement Color
    {
        get
        {
            return (ColorElement)this["color"];
        }
        set
        { this["color"] = value; }
    }
}
```

...and then adding a reference to your section in the app/web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dbservers" type="Namespace.DbServersSection, YourAssembly"/>
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So if I call GetSection("dbservers/connectionStrings) would that work?

Comment: I haven't tried it that way; I've only done `(DbServersConfig)GetSection("dbservers")` and then accessed children through that object.

Comment: Awesome. This is very helpful. I will take some time to read it all over.